# Text File to Array To Excel Exporting Data Text Changing

Tags: c#

I have a project that will generate a report about the text file generated by WinMerge comparing. the language used on that Text file is Japanese.

After the winMerge generate an Text File about the comparing data.

the system will provide a report referring to that text File using the excel.

but after passing the value of the text file to an array, the text inside the array are symbols.

now my question is, how can I get the get the Text inside the Text file that is not converting to symbols.

SAMPLE VALUE OF TEXT FILE.
`YMD管理外_モデル`

VALUE OF ARRAY GET IN TEXT FILE.
`YMD_�S���ڍא.dwg`

question: how can i get the exact text that will not be converted to symbols?

this is the code getting all the lines in Text file.

```
   string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(txtResultPath.Text + "A.YMD(T7862)-1.txt").Skip(4).ToArray();
```

Comment: How are you "seeing" the value in the array?

Comment: I did not ask "what" you where seeing, I was what steps did you do to find out the value. Also you need to include some code in your question. We can't tell you how to fix it without seeing what you did.

Comment: Please include [mcve] to help us find out the issue. The problem sounds like wrong encoding used to write or save the text file.

Comment: i have added the code getting all the lines of Text file sir. Then after passing it to the array, the value change to that symbols.

Comment: I have breakpoint sir. After the debugger hits the breakpoint, then i use `ADD WATCH` to see the value of the array.

Comment: Seems like wrong file encoding. Can you please provide more information in the question